# Documentation on pip.conf

Tags: flask, configuration, pip, pypi

Is anyone awared of the documentation related to pip.conf?

For example, is there any documentation that explains the meaning of `[global]` and `[search]`?

I want to know how this file works in Flask system.

Answer (score 2):

Under the general documentation of [`pip`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#id9), there is a section about [the config file](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#configuration).

There is an explanation of the general concept, such as the `[global]` field, and that you can change the parameter of each command. So the parameters of `[search]` should be those of the [`search`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_search/#pip-search) command.